# Why does `let true = false` fail, and is it really possible to do it?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, keyword

Is it possible to make this work? I originally wanted to see if `true` could be redefined, then I saw `true` is actually a keyword.

Is it possible to "fix" the patterns error and get the "you-can't-assign-to-a-keyword-error"?

```
fn main() {
    let true = false;
}
```

I get:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `false` not covered
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let true = false;
  |         ^^^^ pattern `false` not covered
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=efab0cac40756221cc9d056107149208&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: No. Just don't.

Comment: @trentcl Agree. But there's no harm in testing the limits of a language to see what it will or won't let you do, and try to understand why.

Comment: @trentcl Like @PeterHall says, I'm just pushing the limits, to see how the language/platform behaves in those weird cases, trying to fully understand what I'm trying to learn. Of course this is plain wrong, stupid, etc in real-life code, this is just for educational purposes. As important is to communicate "Don't", also important to communicate "Why not". The initial motivation of why I was trying to do that is because in Go `true := false` works (see https://play.golang.org/p/IYePvGlA1w0)

Comment: It seems to me you know the answer. You can't do it because `true` is a keyword. Go is a different language and it can permit whatever, but Rust doesn't. What do you hope to learn from the answers that you didn't know already?

Comment: Since I later found out that `true` is a keyword, the question is really about pattern matching, and the true answer lies in the link provided by @yorodm answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the use cases of raw identifiers besides new keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000263/what-are-the-use-cases-of-raw-identifiers-besides-new-keywords) => [easy](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=33698417766c4b3b3a18429f27a3fc30&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the error message. You're using an [refutable pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-02-refutability.html) in a `let` binding and `let` only allows for irrefutable patterns.

In other words, when you do this:

```
let variable = value
```

You are not assigning a value to the variable. You're creating a binding where the left side matches something on the right side. It should be an irrefutable pattern because the match must always succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, that's exactly what I needed. Fun fact, using `if let` compiles, and even better, the condition is only executed if the variants on both sides are the same (`if let true = true` or `if let false = false`) so apparently there's no way to shoot myself in the foot even when directly aiming at it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do or why you'd *want* to do it! Most people would consider it a design flaw if a language permitted you to redefine `true` and `false` and I'm sure this has been the topic of at least one installment of [The Daily WTF](https://thedailywtf.com).

> Is it possible to "fix" the patterns error and get the "you-can't-assign-to-a-keyword-error"?

Constant definitions don't allow patterns, so you can get a different error by attempting to redefine `true` as a `const`:

```
const true: bool = false;
```

Which produces an error more similar to what you were after:

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `true`
  --> src/main.rs:1:7 
  | 
1 | const true: bool = false;
  | ^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
```

Comment: When I was learning Rust and learned about `enum`, I actually expected `bool` to be a regular `enum`, so rebinding `true` would have been perfectly fine. This would in my opinion have been a little neater. Also python is perfectly fine with redefining `True` for example: `True = 42; print(True)`, this doesn't change the truethiness of the built-in `True` value, as shown by a subsequent `print([] == [])`.

Comment: You can't rebind enum variants either though? And in Python 2, `True = 42` doesn't rebind `True`, it just shadows it with a local variable definition. (In Python 3 `True` and `False` have been made keywords, so `True = 42` is just a `SyntaxError`.)

Comment: @mcarton Other than the variants being keywords, what about `bool` tells you that it's not an `enum`? Maybe that you can coerce to integer types with `as`?

Comment: I guess maybe I'm being unnecessarily pedantic about the meaning of "rebind". If you consider shadowing a variable to be rebinding the name, then I guess `True = 42` does rebind `True`.

Comment: @trentcl I _think_ Haskell's built-in `Bool` actually is just an ordinary `data` type with two constructors.

Comment: TIL `let None = 42;` is an error. I imagined this would have worked, because the actual variant is `Option::<T>::None` just imported as `None`. But hey, as long as I can `type bool = u32`, everything is fine